# extjs function parameters - why not being used?

Tags: extjs

In ext js, I come across functions like this:

```
SearchWindow.WindowCloseButton.on('click',function(btn,e){
    SearchWindow.hide();
});
```

So on click of close button, the window will be hidden.  But why does the function need those two arguments (btn, e) when they are not being used inside the function? I am a java developer and I am unable to understand this syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't *need* the arguments.  These are the arguments that are passed into the function.  You can use them or not.  The function will work without them if you like this better:

```
SearchWindow.WindowCloseButton.on('click',function(){
SearchWindow.hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks.So what is the best practice regarding when to pass args or not?

Comment: @Kaushik:  Well, *you* don't pass the arguments here -they are passed for you.  You can leave them out of the function definition (like I showed); but it's probably good practice to leave them in.  That way, in the future if you decided to add something to the 'click' event function, it is kind of self-documenting what arguments are available to you.  You *may* want to do something in that function that uses them.

Comment: This is a hand written line of code. Can you please explain how they are 'passed for you' as you say? The developer passes this args right?

Comment: Well the code is hand-written, but when you say:   on('click', function()...your function is called when the user clicks on the WindowCloseButton.  It is called with the button and the event object.  You don't pass in those objects...they are passed in for you...all you do is "click".

Comment: This code is an "event handler".  By writing this, you've said: "please call my function when the user clicks on this button".  Without you doing anything else, the button object, and the event (e) will be passed in to this function.  If you include them in the function signature, then you can use them in the function - if you leave them out you can't.

Comment: That's the best explanation ever. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You don't need them. They are optional.

You only need to put them there if you intended on using them.